# SSRS - How to show data label on stacked bar chart for one value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a stacked bar report that contain multiple value in CallCount and another value which contains the percentage result.  How can I display the data label for the percent result only?

[image]

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Application Category CallCount TTLCount CallCountPercent
IR1 SMO 152198 934984 0.16278139518965
IR1 Price 106735 934984 0.114157033703251
IR2 Accounting 104478 934984 0.111743088651784
Na1 Benefits 82530 934984 0.0882688901628263
Na1 Delivery Inquiry 77854 934984 0.083267735062846